# An example of infinite Galois correspondence

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

I got this question while I am studying infinite Galois correspondence.

Let $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.
It's a fact [ http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9103.pdf ] that this is an infinite Galois extension, and $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p \; / \; \mathbb{F}_p) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Now suppose we want to characterize each sub-extension of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p \; / \; \mathbb{F}_p$ (equivalently each closed subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$). Is there a way to solve this problem using the Fundamental Theorem for infinite Galois extensions?

I'll try to explain my doubt better in the following:
If $q$ is a prime, define $L_q := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}}$. We can show that $[L_q : \mathbb{F}_p] = [\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p : L_q] = \infty$ and Gal$(L_q/\mathbb{F}_p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_q$, where $\mathbb{Z}_q$ denotes the ring of p-adic integers.

Let $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq F \subseteq L_q$ a field, and consider $q^{n_F} = $ sup$\lbrace \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert x \in F  \rbrace$, with $0 \leq n_F \leq \infty$.

It's not hard to show that $F = \mathbb{F}_{p^{n_F}}$ (with the convention that $L_q = \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{\infty}}}$) and so every closed subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ can be seen as Gal$(L_q/\mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}})$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$.

Consider now the Frobenius of $L_q / \mathbb{F}_p$ and denote it as $\phi$. We have $\mathbb{Z}_q \cong Gal(L_q / \mathbb{F}_p) = \overline{\langle \phi \rangle}$, and also $\overline{\langle \phi ^ {q^n} \rangle}$ fixes $\mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}}$, but doesn't fix $\mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n+1}}}$, and so $Gal(L_q / \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}}) = \overline{\langle \phi^{q^n} \rangle}$.
But if $\varphi: \overline{\langle \phi \rangle} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_q$ is the isomorphism such that $\phi \mapsto 1$, then the restriction $\varphi_{|\overline{\langle \phi \rangle}}$ gives us an isomorphism 
$$\varphi_{|\overline{\langle \phi^{q^n} \rangle}} : \overline{\langle \phi^{q^n} \rangle} \rightarrow q^n \mathbb{Z}_q$$
such that $\phi^{q^n} \mapsto q^n$.
So it's clear that we can carachterize  each closed subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ as $q^n \mathbb{Z}_q$, with $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$ and the convention that $q^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_q = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.
I would like to apply this particular fact to the initial problem and prove that each closed subgroup of  $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is in the form $\prod_{q} q^{n_q} \mathbb{Z}_q$, for a certain $n_q \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty  \rbrace$.

Thanks

Comment: The fundamental theorem is what tells you that sub-extensions are in bijection with closed subgroups. What more do you want it to do?

Comment: I apologize for the question if it wasn't so clear. I've expanded the last part of the question, trying to explain better my doubt. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we want to find each sub-extension of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p/\mathbb{F}_p$, equivalently each closed subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Let $q$ a prime, and denote $L_q := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}}$. It's easy to verify that $L_q$ is a union of concentric extensions, $\vert L_q : \mathbb{F}_p \vert = \infty = \vert \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p : L_q \vert$ and $\text{Gal}(L_q : \mathbb{F}_p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_q$;

Let $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq F \subseteq L_q$ an intermediate field and let $q^{n_F} := \text{sup}_{x \in F} \lbrace \vert \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert \rbrace$, with $0 \leq n_F \leq \infty$.
Claim: $F = \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n_F}}}$.

[$\subseteq$] 
If $n_F = \infty$ then the inclusion is obvious. Suppose $n_F < \infty$; let $x \in F$, so $\vert \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert \leq q^{n_F}$, but for the costruction of $L_q$ we have $\vert \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert \; | \; q^{n_F}$, and from the well-know theory about  finite field we immediately obtain $\mathbb{F}_p(x) \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n_F}}}$.

[$\supseteq$] If $n_F = \infty$ there exist elements of arbitrary big degree over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but for each $x \in \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}}$ the dimension $\vert \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert$ is finite; again, from the construction of $L_q$ we have $\mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}} \subseteq F$. Suppose $n_F < \infty$, then there exists $x \in F$ such that $\vert \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert = q^{n_F}$ and so $\mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n_F}}} = \mathbb{F}_p(x)$

We can now use the Foundamental theorem for infinite galois extensions and  carachterize each closed subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ as $\text{Gal}(L_q / \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^n}})$, with $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$.

Claim: each closed subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is in the form $q^n\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Let $\phi$ the Frobenius of $L_q / \mathbb{F}_p$. We have $\mathbb{Z}_q \cong \text{Gal}(L_q / \mathbb{F}_p) \cong \overline{\langle \phi \rangle}$.
For the same reason $\text{Gal}(L_q / \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^m}}) \cong \overline{\langle \phi^{{q^m}} \rangle}$, but if we consider the isomorphism
$$\varphi: \overline{\langle \phi \rangle} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_q$$
such that $\phi \mapsto 1$,
which bind $\overline{\langle \phi \rangle}$ and $\text{Gal}(L_q / \mathbb{F}_p)$, and denote $1 := \lbrace \big[ 1 \big]_{q^n} \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, we have that the restriction
$$\varphi_{|_{\overline{\langle \phi^{{q^m}} \rangle}}} : {\overline{\langle \phi^{q^m} \rangle}} \rightarrow {q^m\mathbb{Z}_q}$$
that is the map such that $\phi^{q^m} \mapsto q^m$, define an isomorphism between $\overline{\langle \phi^{{q^m}} \rangle}$ and $q^m\mathbb{Z}_q$. Again we have denoted $q^m :=  \lbrace \big[ q^m \big]_{q^n} \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

In conclusion each closed subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ can be seen as $q^m\mathbb{Z}_q$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$.

Consider now the general case, that is a generic intermediate field of $K$ of$\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p / \mathbb{F}_p$.
Leq $q$ a generic prime and denote $K^{(q)} := K \cap L_q$. We'll show that $$K = \prod_{q}K^{(q)}$$
where $\prod_{q}K^{(q)}$ is the smallest subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ that contains each $K^{(q)}$.

[$\subseteq$] Let $x \in  K$. we say that $\vert \mathbb{F}_p(x) : \mathbb{F}_p \vert = m$, with $m = q_1^{e_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot q_r^{e_r}$; so, for the cinese remainder theorem we obtain that $x \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m} = \prod_{i}\mathbb{F}_{p^{q_i^{e_i}}} \subseteq \prod_{i}K^{(q_i)}$.

[$\supseteq$] obviously because each $K^{(q)}$ lives in $K$.

For what we have said is clear that $K^{(q)} = \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n_q}}}$, for some $n_q \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$, so
$$K =  \prod_{q}\mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n_q}}}$$
For each $q$ consider the morphism
$\theta: \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/K) \rightarrow \text{Gal}(L_q / K^{(q)})$ such that $\sigma \mapsto \sigma_{|_{L_q}}$ .
note that the choice of the codomain is correct, since if $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/K) \subseteq \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/ \mathbb{F})$, so we have $\sigma_{|_{L_q}} \in \text{Gal}(L_q/ \mathbb{F})$ and it is an automoprhism of $L_q$ which clearly fixes $K^{(q)}$. All these morphisms generate a map
$$\theta: \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/K) \rightarrow \prod_{q}\text{Gal}(L_q / K^{(q)})$$
such tath $\sigma_{|_{L_q}} \mapsto \sigma$

But the extensions of $ K^{(q)} = \mathbb{F}_{p^{q^{n_q}}}$ have trivial intersection, i.e $\mathbb{F}_p$, and so it's easy to verify that $\theta$ is a bijective morphism, that is
$$\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p} / K) \cong \prod_{q}\text{Gal}(L_q / K^{(q)}) \cong \prod_{q}q^{n_q}\mathbb{Z}_q$$
Finally, all closed subgroups of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ are in the form $ \prod_{q}q^{n_q}\mathbb{Z}_q$, with $n_q \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$.